# Getting image dimensions for images that do not have width and height specified in source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get the height and width of an image that does not have its width and height tag specified in the HTML source.

ie

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/imge.jpg" id="my_img" />
```

What I want to do is get the image's width and the height before it loads up. I am trying to achieve the following task, if you know a better solution please suggest me.

I want to do this because I would like to keep all of the images in my site to less than or equal to 600px. So if an image's width > 600px, I reduce it to 600px. Or else I leave its width unchanged.

My tryouts: None of the codes below work for this task, as they get the image's size once the image is loaded; initially they display zero for width.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var img = document.getElementById('my_img');
  var width = img.clientWidth;
  var height = img.clientHeight;
  alert('Width: ' + width + ' Height:' + height); // FAIL

  var timg = document.getElementById('test').width;
  alert(timg);  // FAIL too
</script>
```

My HTML code:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/imge.jpg" id="my_img" />
```

Hope this is clear.

Thank you.

Comment: "What I want to do is get the image's width and the height before it loads up." -- well, if that was possible, the browsers would do it for you. You need to wait for the information.

Comment: Use JQuery : $('#my_img').height() and $('#my_img').width() to retrieve the image size. But in your case, you need to use CSS as proposed by @Giona

Comment: @sdespont I think this will work after image is loaded in page, right? printfmyname, I think you can do this in server side code, like java or php.

Comment: The image height and width is ONLY known after the image has been retrieved/loaded by the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z6v4E/)

Why use JavaScript? With this CSS rule you can limit the width to `600px`:

```css
#my_img { max-width:600px; }
```

Comment: such a genius answer.. Thanks to  Giona and arttronics. and everyone else took time to answer.